# Datatable js interferes with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, dropdown

I have a navigation bar using bootstrap nav-pills with a dropdown that works fine, it looks like this:

```
 <li class="dropdown"  >
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/admin   /faqs"  class="active">FAQ Admin
<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="active"><a href="/admin/faqs/index.php">FAQ Admin</a></li>
  <li ><a href="/admin/faqs/sort.php">FAQ Order</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
```

but when I need to use datatables on a page which requires this js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

the pull down stops working..if you take the above script out, it works again.  Does anybody have a fix for this interference?

Comment: Try installing both through bower and use the bootstrap version of datatables: `bower install --save datatables.net-bs`. (Source: https://datatables.net/download/bower)

Comment: So you're saying the only way to do this by using the datatables version of bootstrap?  If so, I hope they update the bootstrap files all the time since I need to latest version of bootstrap.

Comment: There might a different way to do it: For example fiddle around with the order in which you're including the scripts. However I think that by using bower and the right modification of datatables you'll be able to achieve more consistent and more reliable results.

Comment: Thanks..messing around with the order and what goes into the cdn files helped...